# KVM VM - copy and paste without host clipboard access

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, clipboard, libvirt

I've been trying to look for an option to copy and paste into/from my Debian KVM/QEMU virtual machine without giving the VM access to the host clipboard, and without the host having access to the VMs clipboard.

The host is running Debian 11 w/ KDE and the VM is Debian 11 w/ XFCE4 (managed with virt-manager)

My reason is that I would be copying and pasting things around the host OS (passwords and such) that I do not want the VM being able to see, and the same for inside the VM.

My current, very rough solution, is a shared filesystem to a directory in /tmp on both the VM and the host and have a file there that I have some bash scripts reading and writing to one line at a time. So I launch a terminal with two windows, and paste things I want to share with the VM in there, and the VM can paste things I want to share with the host.

Unfortunately, I don't really like this solution, it's inconvenient. I'm not totally opposed to using the mounted shared filesystem for the communication channel, but I can't find much for linux in regards to "real-time file editing" or file based clipboards as already-made software.

Ideally, there would be an alternate keybinding on both OS's (alt-c, alt-v) that copies selected data into a separate shared clipboard between host and VM. I have played around with KDE global keyboard shortcuts, but the problem comes down to reading text selections from a program in a script called by the shortcut.

I keep running into walls trying to solve this problem, I'm looking for ideas, suggestions, software or other recommendations on a good solution for separated clipboard sharing between VM and host.